# Select/Option Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, html-select, laravel-5.3

I want to use select and option in laravel 5.3 in simple HTML form. How to use select and option in  laravel 5.3 in HTML form?

My coding:

```
@extends('layout.navigation')
<html>
<head>
</script>
</head>
<div class="row" id="contact_form">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<form action="{{route('online_form')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{!!csrf_field()!!}
<br/><br/>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="form_panel">
<div class="panel-body">
<p>fill the form </p>
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
<br/>
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required><br/>
<p style="margin-top:20px;font-size:14px">Gender :&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <label 
class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" style="margin-top:1px" name="gender" 
value="Male">Male</label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" style="margin-top:1px" 
name="gender" value="female">Female<br/></label>
<p style="margin-top:20px;font-size:14px"> Select Language 
:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" 
name="language" value="english">English</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="language" 
value="hindi">Hindi</label>
<br/><br/>
<select id="state">
<option value="rajasthan">Rajasthan</option>
<option value="madhya pradesh">Madhya Pradesh</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter" class="btn btn-primary" >
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try anything so far ? Do you mean the `HTML::Form` method to create select/option ?

Comment: Are you using composer or dependencies?

Comment: i have created my project using composer

Comment: my coding : <select id="state">

Comment: <option value="rajasthan"></option><option value="madhyapradesh">

Comment: how to take value of the option in controller

Comment: just check your `Request` array for `state` index

Comment: What is your issue ? Also, its a good idea to use names instead of ids for retrieving data on server side

Answer (score 0):

To get the state value in the controller method, you can use `Input` facade.

```
$state = Input::get('state');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include the following as a dependency in composer `"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"` and then include it in your config/app

Now, you can create your select dropdown using:

`echo Form::select('gender', array('Male', 'Female'));`

`echo Form::select('language', array('English', 'Hindi'));`

and so on.

For more information on this collective, 
check [this](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html) out.